# Recylerview set header and item from HasMap

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, native, headerfooter

[image: expect result like this]

expect result like that..
and the response from API like this
[image]

then, how to implement it use HasMap and define header and item.
please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have implement it but there is issue, which is the footer is below of item. and this is my code:

```
public class HeaderItemYoutuberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
public static final int HEADER = 1;
private static final int ITEM = 2;
private Context mContext;
List<ListItem> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();
private String guestName= "";
private String imgProfile = "";
private String descGuest= "";
private String posritionGuest= "";

public HeaderItemYoutuberAdapter(Context mContext, List<ListItem> consolidatedList) {
    this.consolidatedList = consolidatedList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}



@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
    final View view;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (type == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.section_header, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(view1);
    } else {
        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.section_item, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view2);

    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
        HeaderItem generalItem   = (HeaderItem) consolidatedList.get(position);
        HeaderViewHolder generalViewHolder= (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;
        generalViewHolder.txtTitleHeader.setText(generalItem.getHeaderYotube().getCategory());

    } else {
        ItemContent dateItem = (ItemContent) consolidatedList.get(position);
        ItemViewHolder dateViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
        if (dateItem.getmStrings().size()>0){
            for (int i = 0; i<dateItem.getmStrings().size(); i++){
                guestName = dateItem.getmStrings().get(i).getGuestName();
                imgProfile = dateItem.getmStrings().get(i).getImgProfile();
                descGuest = dateItem.getmStrings().get(i).getDesc();
            }
        }

        dateViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(guestName);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imgProfile)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.image_placeholder))
                .fitCenter()
                .into(dateViewHolder.imgContent);
        dateViewHolder.txtDesc.setText(descGuest);        }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return consolidatedList != null ? consolidatedList.size() : 0;
}


private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return consolidatedList.get(position).getType();

}

class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView txtTitleHeader;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.txtTitleHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_header_section);

    }
}

class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView txtTitle;
    protected ImageView imgContent;
    protected TextView txtDesc;

    public ItemViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.txtTitle   = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_youtuber);
        this.txtDesc   = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc_youtuber);
        this.imgContent = v.findViewById(R.id.img_exhibition_item);

    }
}
```

and this is the result what i have[image]